# Callback when test fails with tape

Tags: node.js, testing, node.js-tape

Is it a way to call a function in case of error?

I have a test like that:

```
t.true(ARRAY.every(function(item){
    return item.label
}), 'Every item should have label')
```

So I am looking for a callback to specify which item hasn't label in case of failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me an alternative on the tape github:

> every is for when you want to reduce an array to a boolean, which isn't appropriate for testing (and getting a meaningful failure message) every item in an array.

[Tape issue](https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/190)